# Weighting Survey Data with Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm looking to weight survey data. I can do this in R straightforward enough:

```
wtd.table(df$sex, weights = df$survey_weight)
```

However, I cannot seem to be able to find how to do this in python despite lots of searches!

Does anybody have any python examples on how to produce a weighted frequency of a variable, please?

Many thanks!